# PowerShell: Weird date format string to date time

Tags: powershell, datetime-format, data-conversion, string-to-datetime

I am having trouble handling a weird date format exported from an event log.

It looks like the following:
**Mon May 14 09:32:59 UTC 2018**

And I attempted generic **Get-date**, all the way to:

```
$stringToDatetime2 = [Datetime]::ParseExact("$($TaskFailures[0].time)", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy", $null)
```

I have a feeling I am probably doing something wrong that is obvious. That is the type of feeling I am getting.

Comment: Well, that string is not a valid date. You are going to have to parse it yourself and produce something that can be converted to a date

Comment: Is the date exported in the event? or part of the text *in* the event?

Comment: How is that string not a valid date? It's 1526290379 seconds since the Unix epoch, formatted with the "C" locale, in UTC. Try `LC_ALL=C date -u --date=@1526290379` in bash on a Linux box.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 its a separate column, thankfully .... It is mainly the UTC bit that is throwing me off, as how to process that ZZZ seems to not be working... or any timezone 3-letter indicator  like EST... how would you make get-date or [datetime] recognize that

Comment: Are you using `Get-EventLog` to retrieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you're asking is "how do I get `[DateTime]::ParseExact` to treat 'UTC' as '+0000'?".

I couldn't get that to work, but I did get the following to work:

```
[DateTimeOffset]::ParseExact(
    "Mon May 14 09:32:59 UTC 2018".Replace("UTC", "+0000"),
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
    [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Note the (cheating) `.Replace`.

Unfortunately, I can't find a reliable way to recognise all of the timezone abbreviations. If your log file is only ever in UTC (most are, because servers are usually timezone-agnostic, and configured in UTC), you'll be fine.